# Access store in ember.view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How we can access this.store in Ember.view ?
I tried inject method , but it doesn't work for me . Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an antipattern you want to send an action to the controller and do you work with the store in the controller.

However if you have to inject the store into the view you would do this.

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: "store",

    initialize: function(container, application) {
      application.register('store:main', application.Store);
      ...
    }

    container.lookup('store:main');
  }
});


Application.initializer({
  name: "injectingTheStore",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.inject('view', 'store', 'store:main');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried it but doesn't work for me ... I am using ember-data (beta version) . I need store inside Ember.view

Comment: Why do you need the store inside the view? The controller is the canonical place for doing things with the store below the UI layer.

Comment: I am using one view component , inside that i need store to find a value